# Upper Bound on equation obtained from Discrete Fourier transform(DFT)

Tags: asymptotics, fourier-transform

Here is a equation obtained from Discrete Fourier transform,

$$F(k) = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{l=0}^{n}P^{-lk} \prod_{j=1}^{n}(1+(P^{l-1})p_j)$$
where $p_j=\frac{x_j}{N}, $$
k\in(1,2,3.....n)$, $
x_j\in(1,2,3.....N)$,  $P=\exp^{\frac{2i\pi}{n+1}}$, $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and N is a constant.

Trying to estimate an asymptotic bound involving $n$ and $N$ using Euler-Maclaurin Summation. Is it correct approach to use Euler-Maclaurin Summation for asymptotic upper bound?
Second, if I can estimate upper bound on $P=\exp^{\frac{2i\pi}{n+1}}$, would that be sufficient to calculate a bound on $F(k)$.

Any other methods, solutions and suggestions are welcome !
Seems very hard to find upper bound on this equation.

Comment: Could you clarify where this arises from and what kind of a bound you're seeking?

Comment: This is pmf of Poisson Binomial distribution https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution..I need to calculate upper bounds...

Comment: Then it looks like you have a typo as the product factor should be $(1+(P^l-1)x_j/N)$.

Comment: @AlexR. I have changed it.

Comment: Since $\exp(2i\pi/(n+1))$ is, in general, not a real number, please explain what you mean by an "upper bound."

Comment: @whuber : How $F(k)$ varies with given $k$.What I mean to say is that, a certain bound $O(B)$ such that F(k) will never exceeded this, $F(k) \in O(B)$. As simple example, $f(x) = x^2+x+1$ varies as $O(x^2)$.